# Theano Matrix Inverse

Tags: python, theano

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv
import theano.tensor as T
from theano.compile import function
from theano.tensor.nlinalg import matrix_inverse, det
from theano import shared
from theano import config

A = shared(np.matrix('1 0 0; 1 2 0; 0 0 3', dtype=config.floatX))
print(A.get_value())
invA = matrix_inverse(A)
print(invA)
```

The print(invA) statement prints out "MatrixInverse.0". The matrix does have an inverse. Could someone please help me print out the matrix inverse?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a Theano function to evaluate the symbolic matrix inverse

```
A = T.dmatrix('A')
invA = matrix_inverse(A)
f = theano.function([A], invA)   
print(f(np.matrix('1 0 0; 1 2 0; 0 0 3', dtype=config.floatX)))
#[[ 1.          0.          0.        ]
#[-0.5         0.5         0.        ]
#[ 0.          0.          0.33333333]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.